# Csom code works if alert is implemented

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

This code works if i have a alert before , when i remove it, the isUserInList always shows false.

Maybe i need to have a return value in  CheckIfUserIsInList(); function ?

```
  var isUserInList = false;

        CheckIfUserIsInList();

 alert(isUserInList); //only works if alert

              if(isUserInList == false){
                  ShowDialog();
               }
               else
               {
                console.log("user dont want information");
               }
     }


  function CheckIfUserIsInList(){

           var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

           var currentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
           var thisList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('userData');

           var query = new SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
           var listItems = thisList.getItems(query);

           clientContext.load(currentUser);
            clientContext.load(listItems);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, listSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, listFailed)); 


           function listSuccess(sender,args){

           var userInfo = currentUser.get_title();

           var listItemEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();

             while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext()){

              var olistItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
              var userItem = olistItem.get_item("Title");

                if( userInfo == userItem)
                {

                  isUserInList = true;

                }
                else
                {
                  isUserInList = false;
                }
             }

           }


           function listFailed(sender,args){
          console.log('List retrieved error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
           }

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this

```
if(isUserInList == false){
    ShowDialog();
}
else
{
    console.log("user dont want information");
}
```

into `listSuccess`

```
function listSuccess(sender,args){

       var userInfo = currentUser.get_title();
       var listItemEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();

        while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext()){
          var olistItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
          var userItem = olistItem.get_item("Title");

          if(userInfo == userItem)
          {
              if(isUserInList == false){
              ShowDialog();
          }
          else
          {
              console.log("user dont want information");
          }
      }
      else
      {
         console.log("user not in list");
      }
   }
}
```

Or use somethink like jQuery.deffered to check that the event is actually finished before checking the value: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/